# angularjs html codes to symbols in a directive doesnt work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

```
crmApp.directive('udArrow', function () {
return {
    Restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var upArrow = '&#x2191;';
        var downArrow = '&#8595';
        scope.resultTemplate = '';
        if (attrs.val1 > attrs.val2) {
            scope.resultTemplate =(upArrow);
        }
        else {
            scope.resultTemplate = (downArrow);
        }
    },
    template: '<span>{{resultTemplate}}</span>'
}
```

});

the result is (i seperated semicolon on purpose not to make up arrow ) 
&#x2191 ;

i do appreciate better solutions too. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [ng-bind-html](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)

```
crmApp.directive('udArrow', function () {
return {
    Restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var upArrow = '&#x2191;';
        var downArrow = '&#8595';
        scope.resultTemplate = '';
        if (attrs.val1 > attrs.val2) {
            scope.resultTemplate =(upArrow);
        }
        else {
            scope.resultTemplate = (downArrow);
        }
    },
    template: '<span><div ng-bind-html="resultTemplate"></div></span>'
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alot Arun ,saved me a good time  thanks again so much .